# Noetherian, self-injective ring $R$ with non-torsionless $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, noetherian, projective-module

Let $R$ be an (associative, unital) ring. By an $R$-module we mean a left $R$-module. We call an $R$-module *torsionless* if it can be embedded into a direct product of the regular $R$-module $R$.

I am looking for a Noetherian ring $R$ that is an injective $R$-module over itself which has the property that not every $R$-module is torsionless. Does such a ring exist? What would be an example? Where should I look for an example?

Comment: Note that a Noetherian self-injective ring is automatically Artinian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ring that is Noetherian on a side and self-injective on a side is quasi-Frobenius.  The Faith-Walker theorem says that every injective module of a QF ring embeds in a free module.  Since every module embeds in its injective envelope, we get that every module over a quasi-Frobenius ring is torsionless.

So no, there is no such example.

Comment: Alternatively (kind of): If $R$ is a Noetherian, self-injective ring, then an $R$-module is projetive iff it is injective (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250378/self-injective-noetherian-rings)). Thus, for any $R$-module its injective envelope is projective, and thus embeds into a free $R$-module (aka a direct sum of the regular $R$-module). Now, the direct sum of $R$-modules embeds into the direct product.

Comment: @MaxDemirdilek Yes!  Also an excellent way.